# Sharepoint Business Connectivity Service PrincipalIdentityNotMappedException

Tags: bcs

Today all external lists on farm suddenly stopped working and I cannot configure any BCS application in central admin configuration.

There are

> System.Security.Principal.IdentityNotMappedException

in ULS logs of BCS.
How can I get the exact name of missing account?